# Sound not working after installing Ubuntu

Tags: sound, acer

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and since then my sound doesn’t work.

I have an Acer Aspire 5935g and I have tried everything the Internet has recommended.

It seems to have the cards but I’m not sure.

Comment: In a terminal, type `lspci -knn`, find the section that says *Audio device* and edit your question to contain that section please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Click the speaker icon in the top right of the desktop screen. Click sound settings. Under output, make sure it is set on the device that you want to play sound through. (I also had this problem when switching from Windows 10)

Comment: I have tried this and tested both options there and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this problem, looking on an Italian forum:

In the terminal type:

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

And then you add the following line at the end of the document

```
options snd_hda_intel model=acer-aspire-8930g
```

It did the trick for me on Acer 5935G, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have done various installations/disinstallations, but I think this was the main part

Full thread on Ubuntu Italy can be found here: 
https://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=542503&start=60